# Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()' while using tesseract library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have tried to import tesseract ocr project in android studio. While building gradle it showin error as following

> Error:(8, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
>   Possible causes:
>
> The project 'textfairy' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>   Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>   Apply Gradle plugin

My app/build.gradle file

```
    import java.util.regex.Pattern

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'



    import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os


    task ndkBuild(type: Exec,description: 'run ndk-build') {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        workingDir 'src/main/jni'
        commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-j',     Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()

    } else {
        workingDir 'src/main/jni'
        commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build", '-j',  Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(ndkBuild)
}


    def getVersionCodeFromManifest(String prefix) {
    def manifestFile = file("src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode=\"(\\d+)\"")
    def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestText)
    matcher.find()
    def version = prefix + matcher.group(1)
    println sprintf("Returning version %s", version)
    return Integer.parseInt("$version")
}




    android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        //testHandleProfiling true
        //testFunctionalTest true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            //runProguard true
            proguardFile file('android.pro')
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        x86 {
            versionCode getVersionCodeFromManifest("6")
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86"
            }

        }
        aV7 {
            versionCode getVersionCodeFromManifest("2")
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
        aV5 {
            versionCode getVersionCodeFromManifest("1")
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi"
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            //jniLibs.srcDirs = ['native-libs']
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
            jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build
        }
    }
}

    def Properties props = new Properties()
    def propFile = new File('signing.properties')
    if (propFile.canRead()) {
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

    if (props != null && props.containsKey('STORE_FILE') &&    props.containsKey('STORE_PASSWORD') &&
            props.containsKey('KEY_ALIAS') && props.containsKey('KEY_PASSWORD')) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(props['STORE_FILE'])
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = props['STORE_PASSWORD']
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = props['KEY_ALIAS']
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = props['KEY_PASSWORD']
    } else {
        println 'signing.properties found but some entries are missing'
        android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
    }
} else {
    println 'signing.properties not found'
    android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
}

    dependencies {
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.2'
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:18.0"
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.5'
    compile project(":tess-two:tess-two")
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'

    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.17'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19"
    testCompile("org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc2") {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }


}
```

My project root build.gradle file

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }

    }

}

dependencies {
    apply plugin: 'osgi'
    compile project(':libraries:tess-two')
}
```

My settings.gradle file

```
    include ':libraries:tess-two'
include ':app'
```

My gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

I have added dependencies also. Please tell me what is the problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your top-level `build.gradle`, removing the compile line, and adding the gradle and fabric plugin.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        jcenter()
    }
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }

    }

}
```

Als if you want to use the libraries:tess-two in your project, you have to add this line inside the `dependecies` block of your `app/build.gradle` file

```
compile project(':libraries:tess-two')
```

Finally move the `apply plugin: 'osgi'` at the beginning of the `app/build.gradle` file

To resolve the ndk issue you have to:

1. add gradle.properties file to root folder of your project
2. add 'android.useDeprecatedNdk=true' to gradle.properties file

Here is my gradle.properties :

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Comment: hi Angela that is also i tried. But same error showing. :(

Comment: I added gradle-wrapper.properties file in my question in that any problem is there or not. see my error in that open gradle-wrapper.properties file like that showing

Comment: It is correct. You can also use 2.4.
Make sure to remove the compile statement from your top-level build.gradle

Comment: after removing compile line in top-level build.gradle file. Now showing     Error:(68, 0) Error: NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin.  Consider trying the new experimental plugin.  For details, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.  Set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" in gradle.properties to continue using the current NDK integration.

Comment: yeah i added that line. now showing previous error dsl method not found like that.